# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, react-native

I use one library called nexx it is a video player. I have some crashes depend on `TouchListener`. I really have no idea what is wrong. This is the issue

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnTouchListener(android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference
       at com.awesome.app.video.NexxPlayerActivity.onPlayerError(Unknown Source:36)
       at tv.nexx.android.player.NexxPlayerAndroidImpl.notifyError(Unknown Source:19)
       at tv.nexx.android.player.NexxPlayerAndroidImpl.onPlayerLogicError(Unknown Source)
       at tv.nexx.android.player.logic.PlayerLogicStateMachine.firePlayerLogicError(Unknown Source:24)
       at tv.nexx.android.player.logic.PlayerLogicStateMachine.onMediaError(Unknown Source:16)
       at tv.nexx.android.player.logic.PlayerLogic$2.onMediaError(Unknown Source:6)
       at tv.nexx.android.player.logic.MediaManager$3.run(Unknown Source:23)
       at tv.nexx.android.player.TransactionGetMedia$1.onFail(Unknown Source:16)
       at tv.nexx.android.player.apiv3.APIManager$7$2.run(Unknown Source:6)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

I use `OnTouchListener` only like this nothing more:

```
    @Override
public void onPlayerError(String reason, String details) {
    Log.e(TAG, reason + " " + details);
    this.root.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    });
    this.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

this part `com.awesome.app.video.NexxPlayerActivity.onPlayerError(Unknown Source:36)` says it is into this two listeners but what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `this.root` view is null on some cases when player throws error. I don't really know flow you implemented, but you should want to check if it's `null` or not before setting `onTouchListener` and take another act if it is, or solve why it is `null`.